# Sending a request within a Page Tab

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to send a request within a **page tab app**.

The request that i am sending is a simple message and should essentially allow a user to come to my page and eventually the app page.

The request should display a message but is sending a "Try Now" message which i don't want to.

For e.g

http://cl.ly/image/0F202a2r2Z1r

Additionally the URL that the user is redirected to is as shown below

http://cl.ly/image/2M1s0f1h1J1S

The correct url should be: facebook.com/pages/xxxxx/472145392820013?sk=app_492093050813464

Here is my code so far

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>


<script>



  FB.init({
    appId  : 'xxxxxxx',cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true ,
    frictionlessRequests: true
  });


  function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({
      message: 'My Great Request',
      method: 'apprequests',
      redirect_uri: 'http://google.com',
    }, requestCallback);
  }


  function requestCallback(response) {
    alert(response);
  }



</script>
```

Comment: Please note i added the redirect_uri for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Method `apprequests` will always redirect client to your application canvas page.
Solution. You can check if client is looking at your canvas page (redirected by facebook) and than redirect client to your page tab:

```
<script>
  (function(w){
    w.open("//url_to_your_page_tab", "_top");
  })(window);
</script>
```

Comment: Rather complicated redirecting construct there – might even get problematic if the user uses some kind of weird popup blocker that overwrites the window.open method (yes, such things are out there). I’d go with the good old plain `top.location.href="…"` instead. No need for anonymous self executing function.

Comment: @CBroe `top.location` is not really reliable solution for iframe apps because of Same origin policy ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy )

Comment: You are not allowed to _read_ the value because of the SOP – but you can always _set_ a new value to navigate, without the SOP interfering.